# Firebase load too long to verify installation

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

i develop an application using flutter and I connect it with firebase. using my device not android emulator. but is it normal for firebase load too long to verify installation ? it been checking for an hour. i don't know where the problem is. i tried uninstall apps on my phone and run it again but the result still the same

Answer (score 1):

It sometimes happen. Simple way to test the integration is by getting a firebase token, if you get the token successfully, you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with that step, however you can keep doing your stuff as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do check your internet connection. Many times this does happen because of poor internet connection. Try to elaborate on your question with related images and code. Do check in android studio in tools->firebase->authentication or whatever you are trying to connect is connected to firebase or not.

Comment: thankyou sm for the info! but the current problem is android studio didnt find lib/main. this happen when i want to sync with gradle

Comment: have you implemented dependency for firebase?? check out the JSON file added into the project or not.